# How to add current_user to user_id to form_for in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for

I have a form for creating materials (title, description and content - all basic). The form saves these details just fine but it doesn't save the user_id, which should be the user_id of the current_user. How do I do this? It must be easy but nothing has worked so far.

```
def create 
   @material = Material.new(params[:material])
   if @material.save
     flash[:success] = "Content Successfully Created"
     redirect_to @material
   else
     render 'new'
   end
end
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
def create 
 @material = Material.new(params[:material])
 @material.user_id = current_user.id if current_user
 if @material.save
  flash[:success] = "Content Successfully Created"
  redirect_to @material
 else
  render 'new'
 end
end
```

Answer (score 5):

There are a few different ways to do it depending on how you have your application setup. If there is a relationship between the user and materials (User has many materials), you could use that in your controller:

```
def create
  @material = current_user.materials.new(params[:material])
  # ...
end
```

If you don't have that relationship, I would still recommend setting it in the controller as opposed to a hidden field in the form. This will be more secure because it won't let someone tamper with the user id value:

```
def create
  @material = Material.new(params[:material].merge(user_id: current_user))
  # ...
end
```

Comment: Yeah I've been thinking about setting the associations. I held back because though a user does create materials, there may come a time when several users create materials and I didn't want to deal with that yet. Thanks though!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are saving the login users's object in the `current_user` following will work for you

```
   @material = Material.new(params[:material])
   @material.user_id = current_user.id
   if @material.save
```

Answer (score 0):

With Rails 5 and parameters needing to be `permit`ted before objects are created, this is the simplest way to merge the `current_user` into the params, kudos to @Peter Brown in his answer:

```
def create
  @discussion = current_user.materials.new(new_material_params)
  # ...
end

private
def new_material_params
  params.require(:material).permit(:title, :description,: content)
end
```

If you have *nested* object creation using `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, you need to manually merge deep into the association parameters:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :discussions # Used to associate User with Discussion later
end

class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end

class Discussion < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments
end

class DiscussionsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    # Merge the params[:discussion][:user_id] by using the relationship's #new
    @discussion = current_user.discussion.new(new_discussion_params)
  end

  private
  # Sanitized params for creation, not editing
  def new_discussion_params
    params.require(:discussion)
      .permit(:title, :user_id, 
              comments_attributes: [:id, :content, :discussion_id, :user_id])
      .tap do |discussion_params|
        # Require the association parameters, and if they exist,
        # set :user_id for each.
        discussion_params.require(:comments_attributes).each do |i, comment|
          comment.merge!(user_id: current_user.id)
        end
    end
  end
end
```

**Heads up:** Setting (or overwriting!) what will be `params[:discussion][:comments_attributes]["0"][:user_id]` works fine for creation. But if you allow *editing* deep hierarchies in addition to *creation*, make sure you don't accidentally overwrite all the `:user_id`s with the current user.